# Url template tag and NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-templates

I pass array of objects from view to template, where I want to generate URLs for each object (to different view). So, I have in my URLconf:

```
    url(r'^item/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$',
    'show_item',
    name='show_item'),
```

In template, I iterate on object list and try to generate URL which fits to above URL example, so I pass 2 params to each one:

```
    {% for item in items %}
        Item: {{ item.title }}, description: {{ item.description }}
        URL: {% url show_item item.id item.slug %}
    {%  endfor %}
```

Unlucky, I get django error:

```
Reverse for 'show_item' with arguments '(1, u'first-item')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your urls your `slug` regex needs to contain a hyphen (and might as well add an underscore while we're at it): `(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are named:

```
 {% for item in items %}
     Item: {{ item.title }}, description: {{ item.description }}
     URL: {% url show_item id=item.id slug=item.slug %}
 {%  endfor %}
```

[Documentation for named groups in urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)

Comment: Sorry, but what makes them named?
I did change, but I still get:
Reverse for 'show_item' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 1, 'slug': u'first-item'}' not found.

Comment: The named regex groups: `(?P<id>...`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong show_item should be quoted and parameters named

```
{% url 'show_item' id=item.id slug=item.slug %}
```

also check what is generated by url using:

```
{% url 'show_item' id=item.id slug=item.slug as foo %}
{{ foo }}
```

"as foo" allows you to see the generated url without raising errors.